# JQUERY 'on' statement not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-on

I have a simple button that when clicked, changes its class. I have a second script which tries to detect that class being clicked again.

They need to be able to be clicked on and off.

//// Archive button clicked WORKS
//// Un Archive button clicked DOESN't WORK

### Jquery 1.9

```
//// Archive button clicked
$('a.archive_butt').on("click", function() {

    //// Put the li in as an object
    var li = $(this).parent('li');
    var entry_id = $(li).attr('rel');

    //// Add class to the li            
    $(li).addClass('status_archived');

    //// Swap the Archive button for unarchive
    $(this).addClass('unarchive_butt');
    $(this).removeClass('archive_butt');
    $(this).empty();
    $(this).text('Un-Archive');

    return false;
});



//// Un Archive button clicked
$('a.unarchive_butt').on("click", function() {
    alert('Fire');  
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Can you show the relevant HTML?

Comment: An event is only bound to the elements that match the selector **at the time it's bound**, and not when you change the class in the future. You'd need delegated event handlers for that, and Charlino seems to have that covered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The click event is bound when you call the `.on` but no elements with the class `unarchive_butt` exist when you call it, so it's never bound.

What you really want is the old jQuery `.live()` functionality which has become obsolete in favour of the code below:

```
$('body').on('click', 'a.archive_butt', function() {
    //do stuff
});

$('body').on('click', 'a.unarchive_butt', function() {
    //do stuff
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I would do:

```
    //// Archive button clicked
$('a.button').on("click", function() {        
    if ($(this).hasClass("archive_butt")){
       $(this).text('Un-Archive');
       //and all other stuff you are doing
    } 
    else{
       $(this).text('Archive');
       //and all the other stuff you are doing...
    }    
    $(this).toggleClass("unarchive_butt").toggleClass("archive_butt");
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7n5tz/

Answer (score 0):

change

```
$('a.unarchive_butt').on("click", function() {
```

to

```
$('a.unarchive_butt').live("click", function() {
```

Answer (score 0):

The `.live()` method is deprecated as of 1.7, and should no longer be used.

[jQuery `.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

> As of jQuery 1.7, the **.on()** method provides **all functionality required** for attaching event handlers.
>   ...
>   `.on( events [, selector ] [, data ], handler(eventObject) )`
>   ...
>   If `selector` is omitted or is null, the event handler is referred to as *direct* or *directly-bound*.
>   ...
>   When a `selector` is provided, the event handler is referred to as **delegated**.
>   ...
>   **Delegated events** have the advantage that they *can process events from descendant elements that are added to the document at a later time*.

Therefore, try replacing:

```
$('a.unarchive_butt').on("click", function() {
    ...
});
```

With

```
$().on("click", "a.unarchive_butt", function() {
    ...
});
```

Which turns your directly bound event into a delegated event, capable of handling class changes and objects added to the dom at a later time.